# Tensorflow MutableHashTable not updating

Tags: tensorflow, hashtable

Just want a simple hash-table where I can update the keys, but the mutable hash-tables don't update at all

```
import tensorflow as tf
table = tf.contrib.lookup.MutableHashTable(key_dtype=tf.string,
                                            value_dtype=tf.float32,
                                            default_value=-1)
key = tf.constant('hi', tf.string)
val = tf.constant(1.1,tf.float32)
table.insert(key, val)
```

but then, when I check I get `table.size().eval()` is 0 and

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
table.lookup(key).eval()
-1.0
```

so, it is not updating/inserting the keys or values at all. What am I missing?

(python 2.7, tried both tensorflow v0.10 and v1.x)

Answer (score 3):

The `table.insert(key, val)` is basically an operation. You need to run it in order to update the content of the `MutableHashTable`. I.e.:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSesssion()
sess.run(table.insert(key, val))
table.lookup(key).eval() # or sess.run(table.lookup(key))
```

If you need to have the lookup table filled without having to manually doing insertions, consider using `HashTable` (initialized using `KeyValueTensorInitializer`).

Comment: but `table.insert(key, val)` does not have `.eval()` method:
`AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'eval'`

Comment: @user3516773 Sorry, updated my answer. It should be run using `sess.run(...)`, not `.eval()`.